# Show that quadratic parametric equation has no real roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I was asked to prove that, for all values of $m$, the equation $x^2 + 2mx + 2m^2 + m + 1$ has no real roots of $x$. In trying to prove this, I set 
$a = 1$, $b = 2m$, $c = 2m^2 + m + 1$ and found
$$\Delta = b^2 - 4ac = 4m^2 - 8m^2 - 4m - 4$$
I am unable to use this expression to obtain a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$-4a^2-4a-4=-4(a^2+a+1)$, now you can check that $a^2+a+1$ is always positive as a function of a with the same method.
For this equation, $a=1 b=1$ and $c=1$ so $b^2-4ac= 1-4 < 0$. No solutions, and is always positive, so your discriminant $-4(a^2+a+1)$ is always negative and you have no zeros on your original function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate it.

Comment: Actually doesn't using b^2 -  4 ac for  − 4a^2 − 4a - 4 give an all positive value as b^2 -  4 ac is less than 0.

Comment: Got it this time, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

you have found that the discriminant of the given equation is $-4(a^2+a+1)$.

Now you can show that $a^2+a+1>0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

---

You can use the same  reasoning as for the starting polynomial  $x^2 + 2mx + 2m^2 + m + 1$.  Now you have the polynomial $-4(a^2+a+1)$ and, if it has no real roots, it is always negative.  It has no real root if its discriminant 
$\Delta_a$ is negative and we have $\Delta_a= 1-4=-3$ , so $a^2+a+1$ is always positive and  $-4(a^2+a+1)$ is always negative and the starting equation has no real solutions.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Comment: Actually may you elaborate further please, thanks.

Comment: I've added something to my answer.